# Differential equation with constant inside a trig function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I was doing practice exercise for differential equations and couldn't wrap my head around this one:

$$y(x)=\sin(x+C_1)$$

We need to find a differential equation that $y$ satisfies and the $ODE$ should not contain any constants. If the $C_1$ was outside $\sin$, then the answer would be much easier. I tried using different identities, inlcuding: 
$$\sin(x + y) = \sin(x)\cos(y) + \cos(x)\sin(y)$$
$$\cos(x + y) = \cos(x)\cos(y) - \sin(x)\sin(y)$$

But I just could not eliminate the constant because it is inside $\sin$. Any tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: Differentiate twice...

Comment: But it only has one constant, doesn't it mean the differential equation is only first-order, hence only differentiate once?

Comment: How about $y'=\sqrt{1-y^2}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$y=\sin(x+c)\implies y'=\cos(x+c) \implies y''=-\sin(x+c) \implies y''+y=0$$

Answer (score 2):

For this problem, differential equation does NOT have to be first order linear.  There are more than an ODE that works.

Observe that by the trigonometric identity you provided,
$$y(x) = \sin(x + \mbox{c}_1) = \cos(\mbox{c}_1)\sin(x) + \sin(\mbox{c}_1)\cos(x)$$

By calculus, we have the following pattern:
$$\begin{aligned}
y'(x) &= \cos(\mbox{c}_1)\cos(x) - \sin(\mbox{c}_1)\sin(x)\\
y''(x) &= -\cos(\mbox{c}_1)\sin(x) - \sin(\mbox{c}_1)\cos(x)\\
y'''(x) &= -\cos(\mbox{c}_1)\cos(x) + \sin(\mbox{c}_1)\sin(x)\\
y^{(4)}(x) &= \cos(\mbox{c}_1)\sin(x) + \sin(\mbox{c}_1)\cos(x)
\end{aligned}$$

So one of the ODEs that works (and also easy to find for this type of problem) is
$$y^{(4)} = y$$

*Remark*: You can also differentiate $y(x) = \sin(x + \mbox{c}_1)$ without using the identity.  Using chain rule four times, you get $y^{(4)} = y$.

Comment: Thank you. I thought it was limited to linear ODE.

Comment: Those are linear.